# Custom Dimensions and Metrics not accessible through Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Python client

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-reporting-api

I am having trouble accessing custom dimensions available through GUI using their API names. Is there any way to find the actual api name of all available custom dimensions and metrics. Currently I am using name of the format `ga:dimension<indexidfromGUI>` like `ga:dimension4` but this returns a unknown dimension error.

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Unknown dimension(s): ga:dimension11
```

Here is my report body:

```
    body={
        'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '1daysAgo', 'endDate': '1daysAgo'}],
                'metrics': [
                    {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                ],
                'dimensions': [
                    {'name': 'ga:date'},
                    {'name': 'ga:dimension4'},
                    #{'name': 'ga:dimension11'},
                    #{'name': 'ga:dimension13'},
                    #{'name': 'ga:dimension14'},
                ],
                "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "dimensionName": "ga:eventAction",
                            "operator": "PARTIAL",
                            "expressions": ["ScreenView"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ],
            }]
    }
).execute()
```

If the format for api dim name is wrong, how do i find it out? It is not available in Analytics GUI as far as I know. Is there a documentation for this? I am aware of https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.
But this doesnt include custom dimensions.

Comment: Just to double check, these custom dimensions are defined?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I am new to GA. The custom dimensions are ofcourse defined. I have several GUI dashboards using these dimensions. They are also available in custom dimensions tab in Admin>Property Settings.

Comment: https://imgur.com/PI0Na27

Comment: Is the view ID you're using the correct one? It looks from the error that you're getting, the call is making it through. The dimension names are correct. Can you try using this tool and get data back? https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: The error is pretty clear - ViewID does not has dimension11. This happens when the GA Property this ViewID is attached to dimension11 is not defined.

Could you please do the following:
- Locate in GA specific View and confirm that ID match (view id can be found in view admin page)
- go to custom reports for the same view. Create a Custom Report which uses this dimension11

Comment: @Dmitry I had custom reports with these dimensions, metrics on the same view. The view-id was not the problem. Anyways this problem solved itself after two days. I don't know what resolved but it might be something at the admin end which I don't have access to.